# Array of Objects - Swift

Tags: swift, class, object, dictionary

I want to create an arrray of objects I have created. I will include and example of the object. However, every time I try, I get the error: "Expected Declaration". I was also getting an error that the array was unidentified. Is this because I have to mention the class somewhere in the array?

```
class ShapeColour : NSObject {
    var colour:String
    var shape:String
    var image:UIImage

    init(color: String, shape: String, image: UIImage) {
        self.colour = color
        self.shape = shape
        self.image = image
    }

}
```

above is the class, Below is an exmaple

```
 let redTriangleObject = ShapeColour(color: "red", shape: "triangle", image: UIImage(named: "redTriangle.png")!)
```

Bellow is the array

```
mainShapeDict = [blueSquareObject,blueCircleObject,blueTriangleObject,redSquareObject,redCircleObject,redTriangleObject,yellowSquareObject,yellowCircleObject,yellowTriangleObject]
```

Thanks!

Comment: `mainShapeDict` isn't a Dictionary, it's an array.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to say `let` before `mainShapeDict`  :

`let mainShapeDict = [blueSquareObject, blueCircleObject, blueTriangleObject, redSquareObject, redCircleObject, redTriangleObject, yellowSquareObject, yellowCircleObject, yellowTriangleObject]`

That's why it says "Expected Declaration", because you haven't declared mainShapeDict in any other code I'm guessing.

Answer (score 1):

you should declare the array first
like this

```
var mainShapeDict : [ShapeColour] = [ShapeColour]()
```

then you can add "ShapeColour" objects using .append methode

```
let redTriangleObject : ShapeColour = ShapeColour(color: "red", shape: "triangle", image: UIImage(named: "redTriangle.png")!)
mainShapeDict.append(redTriangleObject)
```

Note : mainShapeDict is an array and not a dictionary